# How to make Clojure tests stop tests running in case one of them failed?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I just would like to make the command `lein test` fail right once the first one test case fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `eftest` as a better alternative to default `clojure.test` runner:

How to use?

From the REPL https://github.com/weavejester/eftest#fast-failure

```
user=> (run-tests (find-tests "test") {:fail-fast? true})
```

or using lein plugin https://github.com/weavejester/eftest#plugin

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer, but if you are working on a single problematic test, I use the "focus" feature of lein-test-refresh.  Very cool plugin.

https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh